# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE passenger_details
   (
    bank_card INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(20), 
    mobile INT(15) NOT NULL,
    p_id INT NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (bank_card),
    FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES passenger(p_id) 
    );

INSERT INTO passenger_details 
VALUES (0123012301230123,'blah_@hotmail.com',0872863492,1234);
```

```
select*from passenger_details;
+------------+--------------------+-----------+------+
| bank_card  | email              | mobile    | p_id |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+------+
| 2147483647 | blah_@hotmail.com  | 872863492 | 1234 |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As we can see, the previous value, just went wrong into table. Should be 16 numbers and not only 10, actually different numbers.
When i try to insert a new value:

```sql
INSERT INTO passenger_details 
VALUES (1234258431681842,'blah@icloud.com',0895764829,123548);
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'

If bank_card is AUTO_INCREMENT why there is error? Should I change the PK to another place?

Comment: '2147483647' is the max of a signed `INT`, either change your column cast to `UNSIGNED INT`, or use a `BIGINT` column. [See the manual for the limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). Also, think about whether your column should actually be an autoinc. int. The prefixing `0` in `0123012301230123` might lead me to think there's a possibility a char column is more apt for what it does.

Comment: Note that auto increment only has effect if you don't give any value for the column.

Comment: @Wrikken thats good, i gonna check it out! Tnks
.

Comment: @nos tnks for remanding me

Comment: @Wrikken UNSIGNED is used only for INT am i right? I this case i am using VARCHAR, actually on first time i were using INT but having an error. Then ive change to VARCHAR. 
For sure i need to display 0, there are few cards starting with 0.

Comment: @Hugo: yes, `UNSIGNED` is only for INTs for this purpose. And indeed, a CHAR or VARCHAR seems quite more suitable here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`INT` has a [maximum signed value of 2147483647](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). Any number greater than that will be truncated to that value. What you need to do is change that column to be a `varchar(20)` which will hold strings of up to 20 characters since bank card numbers are strings and not actually numbers (you don't do math with the). You also should remove `AUTO_INCREMENT` as that is not a value you will be incrementing.

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. Spent time trying to figure out. Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Something to ask yourself.  How did the number get that big?  I did not insert 2 billion rows!

Well, possibly you 'burned' that many `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids.  This can happen in man ways:

```
INSERT IGNORE ... -- when the insert is ignored (because it the row already exists)
REPLACE
IODKU
```

and probably others.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL phpmyadmin panel , this is how I got rid from this issue

```
>Go to your Table's structure from  phpmyadmin panel
>> select that PRIMARY column , click on change
>>> Change Column type to "BIGINT" and Attributes to "unsigned"
```

with other SQLs > change column attributes to "BIGINT unsigned"
that worked for me