# How to Insert XML File Into Wordpress Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, wordpress

I have a XML data feed which is [here](http://www.hot-offers.net/wp-content/themes/hotoffers/datafeed_249713.xml).

I am trying to use this function to insert all of the products into a database or update on duplicate key. The duplicate key is the ID on the product element `<prod id="685814171" in_stock="yes" stock_quantity="">`. I am saving this as the SKU field.

**Here is the function**

```
function parse_xml(){
global $wpdb;
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.hot-offers.net/wp-content/themes/hotoffers/datafeed_249713.xml');

foreach($xml->datafeed->prod as $item){

    $att = $item->attributes();

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO wp_pcu_babytoddler_products 
              (sku, title, url, stock_message, price, image, pid) 
            VALUES
              (%d, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
              title = VALUES(title),
              url = VALUES(url),
              stock_message = VALUES(stock_message),
              price = VALUES(price),
              image = VALUES(image),
              pid = VALUES(pid);';

    $sql_prep = $wpdb->prepare($sql,
                        (string)$att->id,
                        (string)$item->text->name,
                        (string)$item->uri->awTrack,
                        (string)$att->in_stock,
                        str_replace('.','',(string)$item->price->buynow),
                        (string)$item->uri->mImage,
                        (string)$item->pId);

    $wpdb->query($sql_prep);
}
}
```

**And here is my database schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_pcu_babytoddler_products` (
  `sku` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  `stock_message` text NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `pid` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `wp_pcu_babytoddler_products` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sku`);
```

This function is partly working as it inserts **136** rows into the databate but there should be **232** as there are in the feed. What am i doing wrong?

I dont have to use the `$wpdb` object to insert these, i just thought it was easier.

**EDIT**

Here is an error i'm getting although the ID 2147483647 doesn't exist in the XML feed, this appears to be effecting the remaining products.

```
WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'sku']
INSERT INTO `wp_pcu_babytoddler_products` 
    (`sku`, `title`, `url`, `stock_message`, `price`, `image`, `pid`) 
VALUES 
    (
    '3083667637', 
    'Baby Dan BabyDen Play Pen Black 2014', 
    'http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=3083667637&a=249713&m=3975', 
    'In Stock', 
    '9849', 
    'http://www.babyandtoddlerworld.co.uk/imagprod/imaglarg/BDAN-Babyden-Black.jpg', 
    'BDAN-Babyden-Black-67116-2600-1400-10'
    )

Array
(
    [sku] => 3083667637
    [title] => Baby Dan BabyDen Play Pen Black 2014
    [url] => http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=3083667637&amp;a=249713&amp;m=3975
    [stock_message] => In Stock
    [price] => 9849
    [image] => http://www.babyandtoddlerworld.co.uk/imagprod/imaglarg/BDAN-Babyden-Black.jpg
    [pid] => BDAN-Babyden-Black-67116-2600-1400-10
)
```

Comment: What error you are getting ? may be due to exceed in execution time causing problem.And are you using woocommerce ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors unfortunately, the script runs successfully but only 136 records show in the database. The only thing I can think is that the ID is being duplicated i.e `(string)$att->id`.
I am using woo commerce but not for this import.

Comment: from your xml file, I find these are products ,there should be plugins for this work, but you coded it .Is there any chance to break the xml file nto parts ?

Comment: I could possibly do that, but would need to create another function to do so. Could it be an idea to create say '10' separate queries that input only 20 products at a time? This would split it up a bit.

Comment: better would be write a function for it and call it before running the query, manually doing this will be hard job .

Comment: do some testing to track down the problem. As a start, you could check if the `foreach-loop` iterates  232 times by adding an echo and a counter.

Comment: I've added a count and its looping 232 times. I've found that im getting a duplicate key error for ID 2147483647, but strangely this number doesnt exist in the product SKUs... any ideas?

Comment: okay, you are on the track! I don't know what happens, though. But: update (edit) your question with your new findings, this will attract users that might be able to help!

Comment: Just found the issue, it is with the SKU as an int(11), the maximum number it can store is 2147483647. It truncates any number above that!

Answer (score 1):

Just found the issue, it is with the SKU as an `int()` in the database, the maximum number an `int()` can store is **2147483647**. It truncates any number above that!

I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20442152/1838483

You just need to change the `int()` to be `varchar(20)`.